# jquery append string with timeout

Tags: jquery, append, settimeout

I have the following script in which a previous ajax call gives the data and types the html out. It works fine except that i can't make every new call typing out on a new line, instead of that it replaces the former data. I tried append but then it types out every word repeatedly with one character added.

```
var isInTag = false;

function typetext() {
var thisChar = data.substr(c, 1);
if( thisChar == '<' ){ isInTag = true; }
if( thisChar == '>' ){ isInTag = false; }
$('#field').html(" "+data.substr(0, c++));
if(c < data.length+1)
    if( isInTag ){
        typetext();
    }else{
        setTimeout("typetext()", 100);
    }
else {
    c = 1;
    data = "";
}
}
```

And in the ajax call:

```
data = '<span class="input">' + data + '</span><br />\n';
c = 0;
typetext();
```

I would appreciate some help.

Comment: Provide a jsfiddle please so we can see what it is doing exactly.

Answer (score 1):

Surely the line:

```
$('#field').html(" "+data.substr(0, c++));
```

Should be:

```
$('#field').append(" "+data.substr(c, c++));
```

As you're not writing it out 1 character at a time, but writing out the string from `0` to the `c++`

Or you can look to use the var `thisChar` rather than `data` to the same effect surely?

Comment: don't need a means to decide where to append to, as you obviously just append to `$('#field')`. eg: `$('#field').append(data.substr(0,c++);`

Comment: Of course, yet that isn't working? Correct? As there's every indication that it should.

Comment: yep - just fixed it though, about to post an answer :)

Comment: That doesn't work, it behaves like append and types out every word repeatedly with one character added, instead of typing the characters out.

Comment: OK, I see. Edited to reflect the change the `subStr`

Comment: yeah didn't notice that first time around, fixed it on mine too. facepalm moment :)

Comment: Indeed! It was very well hidden and only just realised he was looking to write it out one character at a time.

Answer (score 1):

OK there were a couple of problems with your code, I've managed to get a version working (I think) fairly close to what you want.

Have a look here, I've commented the parts I changed to hopefully give a clear view of why I changed them:

http://jsfiddle.net/MjS4t/2/

Basically, there were two problems - first, this line:

`$('#field').html(" "+data.substr(0, c++));`

Should have used the `thisChar` variable, as you had already got the character you wanted to append from the `data` var, not certain but I think the `substr()` call was what was causing it to echo out the wrong characters (or the same one over and over again).

I changed it to:
`$('#field').append(thisChar);` and then moved the `c++` to the next line - this made it easier to read for me.

Next, your timeout call was wrong. Putting quotes around function names only works when you assign the function to a variable like this:

`var functionName = function(){ alert('hello world'); };`

But you used different syntax and declared it like:

`function functionName(){ ... }`

So, I changed the setTimeout call from this:

`setTimeout("typetext()", 100);`

To this:

`setTimeout(function() {typetext()},100);`

This way it showed the text with a slight delay, and typed it out.

See here for more reading on delays using javascript set timeout: http://www.sean.co.uk/a/webdesign/javascriptdelay.shtm

And [$.delay()](http://api.jquery.com/delay/) in jQuery is well worth a read.

Comment: now i've done that, jsfiddle is taking forever to serve pages :(

Comment: you need to come up with some more code to handle HTML tags; appending them one by one to the output will stop them being treated as HTML by the browser. Right now it works perfectly, it just needs fixed for html tags. A better idea would be to have the `<span>` tag there to begin with, and append to that instead of mucking about with tags.

Comment: here's a jsfiddle that works but if repeated it replaces the former inputs: http://jsfiddle.net/eMKYv/

Comment: that seems to work, although I'd advise testing it in an existing website with some floated elements. My feeling is that it might, between the HTML changes, give you invalid HTML and could cause display issues in certain layouts. Also check in IE under these circumstances - otherwise, nice job :)